# Binding datagrid from two different sources

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I need to show results of two different sources in one data grid on another window in W PF. Or probably I'm doing it wrong.
so i have this model

```
class StoreModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string StrName { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan TimeI { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan TimeO { get; set; }
        public string Actions { get; set; }//Added later to see if it works
    }
```

and this view

```
<DataGrid x:Name="strGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Store" Binding="{Binding StrName}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="TimeIn" Binding="{Binding TimeI}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="TimeOut" Binding="{Binding TimeO}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Action" Width="*" x:Name="comboTemp">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:Name="myTemplate">
                            <ComboBox x:Name="ActionCombo" IsReadOnly="True" IsEditable="True" Text="Select Action" SelectionChanged="ActionCombo_SelectionChanged">
                                <ComboBoxItem>Resolved</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>Issued</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>Pending</ComboBoxItem>
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

[image]

My task is to just show these records and selected option(from 3,'Resolved','Issued','Pending') from combo box on another page.
I don't know how to include these 2 items from combo box in another page's data grid.

[image]

I tried to do it my own silly way, i retrieved two combo box's values in an array on selection_changed event(which lead to another issue of index out of bound exception if user try to change the selection third time, any help on this too?) and tried to bind these two source together and didn't work.

```
public partial class StorePage : Window
    {
        List<StoreModel> MainstrModel;
        string[] actions ;
        static int selectedRow;
        static int i = 0;
        public StorePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += StorePage_Loaded;
           actions = new string[2];
            MainstrModel = new List<StoreModel>();

        }

        void StorePage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            selectedRow = MainWindow.selectedRow;

            MainstrModel.Add(new StoreModel() { ID = 1, StrName = "Store1", TimeI = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay, TimeO = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay, Actions = actions[i] });
            MainstrModel.Add(new StoreModel() { ID = 1, StrName = "Store2", TimeI = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay, TimeO = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay, Actions = actions[i] });
            MainstrModel.Add(new StoreModel() { ID = 2, StrName = "Store3", TimeI = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay, TimeO = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay, Actions = actions[i] });
            MainstrModel.Add(new StoreModel() { ID = 3, StrName = "Store4", TimeI = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay, TimeO = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay, Actions = actions[i] });

            strGrid.ItemsSource = MainstrModel.Where(x => x.ID == selectedRow);

        }


        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            new MainWindow().Show();
            this.Close();
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DetailPage detail = new DetailPage();

                detail.detailGrid.ItemsSource = MainstrModel.Where(x => x.ID == selectedRow);


            detail.Show();
            this.Close();
        }



        private void ActionCombo_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox combo = sender as ComboBox;
            string item = combo.SelectedItem.ToString();
            actions[i] = item.Substring(item.IndexOf(':') + 1);
                i++;
        }
    }
```

what should i do to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Don't make `static int i = 0;`, this why you're getting Out of Bounds exception. Not clear how you will handle actions and selected ComboBox value. You can obtain index of selected combobox item like this:

```
ComboBox combo = sender as ComboBox;
int index combo.SelectedIndex;
if (index == -1)
    return; //nothing is selected
actions[index] = item.Substring(item.IndexOf(':') + 1);
```

Better solution is to populate combobox from some data(to have relation selected index - particular action) source and get selected item when selection is changed. Then, when you want to pass the data source to another view, you can safely pass existing datasource in a new view and set combox's SelectedIndex in, for example, DataGrid.LoadingRow.

Comment: what i needed is int index= strGrid.SelectedIndex; not combo.SelectedIndex because it gets the item's index but not the row's(which i needed).thanks for the idea.
and about the main problem, i don't have combobox on the other page just a texblock to show result, so i can't work on selectedIndex

Comment: Grid does not have index to select, except for selected row. Is it what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

First to get selected value from ComboBox, bind SelectedItem / SelectedValue as `SelectedValue={Binding DataContext.Actions, ElementName=ActionCombo}`, this will give you user's action in Actions property in the form : "`System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: Pending`".

Then you can pass either the Actions property value or the filtered data according to Actions property value, either in new window's constructor, or set some property of it depending upon whether you showing a new Page/Window/Dialog.